Can floor joists sistered into existing ceiling be notched at the edge to sit correctly on the outer wall?
I need to turn this 2x8 ceiling into a floor that supports live loads. The ~15ft span will require 2x12s to be sistered to the existing ceiling joists. However if you look at the image below you can see that the existing joists (yellow) have a layer of 2x4s directly over the outer wall (teal) that serve to raise the wall to meet the rafters.

IIUC, the new sistered joists need to extend all the way to the load bearing wall. However, In order to line up with the rest of the second story, I need the new joists to sit on the actual lower wall, and not on the built-up portion. What is the proper way to do this?
Thoughts...

Notch the 2x12s down to 2x8s to fit under the 2x4 built-up portion. This essentially weakens them at the edge down to the strength of a 2x8 (likely less given that the notch introduces a weak point), but does the fact that they are doubled (sistered to the existing 2x8s) make up for that?
Maybe I'm mistaken about how the sistered joists transfer load, and they don't actually need to sit completely on the outer wall to add the required strength?

FWIW I would like this to meet building code.

You can certainly notch the top corner as you describe. That portion of the joist is virtually insignificant in terms of its total capacity. Run it by any involved inspectors, though, to be sure they'll be ok with it. That's where the rubber meets the road.
You could also simply hang the new joists with hanger hardware of a suitable size and configuration and not rest on the lower wall plate at all. Given your nonstandard rim situation, a top-mount hanger would do nicely.
For cost reasons I'd consider engineered (TJI) joists and the hangers I mentioned. They may actually be cheaper than 16' 2x12. I've also found 2x12 to vary substantially in height and they're often crowned fairly severely, resulting in a humpy floor unless you plane them.
